# Amazon kinesis injestion on Apache Druid

Tags: amazon-kinesis, druid

Hi After loading data iam getting unhealthy superviser as status in ingestion

when check the logs errors are

"state": "UNHEALTHY_SUPERVISOR",
"detailedState": "UNHEALTHY_SUPERVISOR",
"recentErrors": [
{
"timestamp": "2022-03-17T12:32:32.925Z",
"exceptionClass": "org.apache.druid.java.util.common.ISE",
"message": "unable to fetch sequence number for partition[shardId-000000000003] from stream",
"streamException": false
}
]

what might be the cause and how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

That error can be thrown when 1 shard is empty, even though data are flowing though the stream in other shards.   Is that the case here? You could bring down the number of shards, make sure that shard some data, or if you're not worried about dropping data, hard reset the supervisor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).